# Ubuntu 12.04 - hard drive shows on two different /dev

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, development

I installed a new HDD on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. I can access the new and all old drives fine, but I just noticed that one of the old drives suddenly shows on two different `/dev` points.

```
/dev/sdc1       2.7T  2.5T   91G  97% /large3tb
/dev/sdd1       2.7T  2.5T   91G  97% /large3tb
```

the `/dev/sdd1` is correct; this is where it is attached, as shown in gparted.

I'm concerned because `/dev/sdc1` is also where the root is attached.

What could be causing this issue?
The drives all seem to work correctly, but I am concerned that something will happen to my root drive.

Looking at `/etc/fstab`, here is what I get for this drive:

```
/dev/sdd1       /large3tb       ext4    defaults 0 0
```

I'm not sure where the `/dev/sda1` is coming from.

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsblk -f` please?